# Is there a function or a method to add " , " after every row in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a .json file which is about 600+ lines and it looks like this:

```
{data0..}
{data1..}
{data2..}
```

To use it i need to add [ before and ] after to make it an array (no problem)
but i need to add " , " after every row. Is there a function/method to do that faster than manual typing?
Every object contain data in it.
Or anything to make it readble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, and simpler,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to select all.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>All</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> to put a cursor at each line end.

Type your <kbd>,</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press `Ctrl-H` for the `Search-Replace` window
2. In the first line type `\n` which means new line and make sure the regular expressions button is pushed - it's 3rd in the row and looks like this: `.*`
3. In the second line type `,\n` - to replace new line with a comma followed by a new line
4. Push the "replace all" button

Notice: it assumes every JSON object occupies strictly single line